# Долгий mysqli запрос

Tags: php, mysqli

Имеется таблица `alog` с содержанием:

```
  id  || userid || text
================================
  1   || 12000  || действие1
...
15014 || 49621  || дейтсвие15014
...
32194 ||  6700  || действие32194
```

Соответственно, более 32 тысяч строк.

Обращаюсь к таблице:

```
$request=$mysqli->query("
SELECT `alog`.`text`,`users`.`login`,`alog`.`userid` 
FROM `alog` 
JOIN `users` 
ON `alog`.`userid`=`users`.`id` 
ORDER BY `alog`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 6
");
```

Затем обрабатываю для каждой строки:

```
for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($request);$i++) 
{
   $rows=$request->fetch_assoc();
   echo '<p class="category">'.$rows['login'].' - '.$rows['text'].'</p>';
}
```

Запрос выполняется несколько секунд.

Какие есть способы сократить время выполнения запроса к таблице с большим количеством строк? Возможно, какие-то дополнительные библиотеки.

Comment: попробуйте вместо таблицы alog в запросе использовать подзапрос: `... FROM (select * from alog order by id desc limit 6) alog` ну и лимит к конце убрать. если не помогает - смотрите план выполнения, сортировка должна идти по индексу

Comment: я бы еще проверил время выполнения напрямую на сервере БД, без пхп.

Comment: @teran, 0,172 сек. Особенность, к слову, в том, что подключение к бд удаленное, не локалхост

Comment: @Mike, действительно помогло, очень интересно как это устроено.

Comment: а циклы выборки обычно пишут `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ }` таки, без постоянных вызовов `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: а устроено так, что в вашем варианте джойнится таблица целиком и потом делается лимит, а в варианте с подзапросом джойнятся только 6 записей. но PK на id и индекс на user_id никто не отменял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте переписать запрос так:

```
SELECT `alog`.`text`,`users`.`login`,`alog`.`userid` 
  FROM (select * from alog order by id desc limit 6) `alog`
  JOIN `users`
    ON `alog`.`userid`=`users`.`id` 
 ORDER BY `alog`.`id` DESC
```

В вашем изначальном запросе MySQL сначала получает все записи из alog, подбирает подходящих для них пользователей и только после этого сортирует всю выборку и берет первые 6 записей.

В варианте с подзапросом, MySQL сначала получает 6 записей, причем скорее всего использует индекс по полю id и не проходит по всей таблице и даже не использует сортировку, так как из индекса записи выбираются сразу в нужном порядке. И только после этого подбирает подходящих пользователей именно для этих 6 записей.